# Editing a post that mentions your answer to hyperlink to it?

Tags: discussion

I was looking through some answers on a question to which I contributed, and another answer said to look at my post. Would it be appropriate to add a hyperlink that then points to my post. The other user specifically mentioned my post, but it seems iffy to edit his post to link to my post if I am the one to do it. Is this useful and acceptable to edit and add a hyperlink?

Answer (score 12):

The other user specifically referred to your post. So IMO adding a link will make the answer more useful.

Comment: Agreed. This is not an ego game, you're doing this to make the content on the site more useful, which is the ultimate goal here.

Comment: But you get ego points for having your ego in check by asking!